# Ubuntu seperate user account internet conncetion

Tags: ubuntu

I have two user accounts on my ubuntu machine. I want to be able make downloads on one account, while I am working on my other user account. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

yes, open a terminal somewhere (ssh, sudo user_name, ctrl+alt+F1...) and type "wget http://www.server.com/download_address". The download will start and you can get back to your own account while the download is still running.

I think you should be more specific on your question

Comment: The downside of this is, that you are bound to the commandline. If you want to download from a oneclick hoster with waitingtime this won't work(at least for the big ones, but there might be commandline clients for them).

Comment: The same way you can open another text console, you can have more than one graphical console, or you can use ssh -X to open a browser as other user.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this at https://askubuntu.com/ but to give an answer: As ubuntu is a multi user system you could login with one account, start the download there, switch to another account and work there.

As I don't have Ubuntu running on my computer I can only describe it vague:
Normally there should be some sort of logout button and also a switch user button,
which will keep the current user session running while enabling you to login with another user.
This button should lead you to the usual login screen where you login as the other user and have
fun doing what you want to do.

At least thats the normal way on all of the linuxes(or linii?) that I posses.

Comment: It's normally best to suggest the different sites in a comment.

Comment: I think I also gave an answer so best would have been to split it into comment and answer.

Comment: @Nobody, indeed, but "switch to another account" is a bit vague. :) _How_ would you switch to another account? That's the thrust of the question. :)

Comment: well thought that to be clear but maybe I should explain it a little more. Unfortunately I have no ubuntu at hand to say the exact steps in clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the virtual desktops. By default Ubuntu comes with 4 (located in the lower right corner. Each desktop is usually used for those purposes. In one desktop you can be downloading, in the other you could be working. You can then just switch between desktops. Hope this helps!

Comment: .. But this doesn't use different user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

As told by "Nobody", you have to use multi user feature of the ubuntu. 
You log in to your regular account and go to top right corner and click on user name you have created only for browsing the net. Do not panic, the screen will change and ask for password. 
Enter the password and you can use it for browsing. Now, you may want to do some offline work. Enter the key F7 while keeping the keys controll and alt(Controll+alt+F7). It will take you to your offline account. Again if you want to switch over to internet account, you can press Controll + alt+F8.

All the best and enjoy.